# simulate real user click bypassing a web honeypot

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, browser, detection

I would like to scrape a web page but I can't be detected as a bot. I am using js to fetch data, fill inputs or click buttons.

I have read that I have to take into account some "diplayed: none" attributes as they seems to be honeypots. In my webe there is a div which shows this:

```
     // When mouse is not used
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 10000;"><div class="tip">
     // When mouse has moved but not on any clickable point
<div style="position: absolute; top: 264px; left: 272px; z-index: 10000; display: none;"><div class="tip">
     // When mouse on a clickabel point
<div style="position: absolute; top: 264px; left: 272px; z-index: 10000;"><div class="tip">
```

This make me think the web check if the click has been done programmatically or if it is from a real user.

Thereby

- Is this something I have to work with or it is insignificant??
- If so, how could I bypass it??

Thank you very much

Comment: Well you could just remove the `display: none` elements, but I can tell that this page is not doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: This code changes the appearance of those buttons. They get a white blur so it seems focused. Nevertheless, I really think the web can be doing something to detect if the user is real or a bot.

Answer (score 1):

*display:none;* isn't your only problem, one could also use negative *left:-100px;* or *top:-100px;* values, and/or *color:white;* on a white background, and so forth.

But they are all foolhardy attempts to prevent bots when all they had to do is this...

Luckily, JavaScript already provides a mechanism for determining if an event was user-initiated via the "**isTrusted**" boolean property. Usage is as follows...

```
<button id="logon" onclick="if(event.isTrusted){SomeFunction();}">Logon</button>
```

Any JavaScript attempt to click this button such as logon.click(); would fail this test and the function would never run, and no there's no way you can simulate a human gesture.

Hackers exploit bad programmers who use foolish tricks like the ones you and I mentioned.

Comment: Whereas this one could be bypassed by simply running `SomeFunction()` directly...

Comment: Added a new post to answer the good point you raise.

Comment: Then, if I have understood you, I cannot get over bot detection if I see any function with event.isTrusted.

Answer (score 0):

Good point raised by Dave, but the version posted was for clarity purposes.

See if you can fool this little modification...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function SomeFunction(event){

if(event.isTrusted){
   
  alert('This came from a human');


 } else {alert('This came from a bot');}
}

</script>

<button id="logon" onclick="SomeFunction(event);">Logon</button>

<button onclick="logon.click();">BOT clicking button</button>

<button onclick="SomeFunction(true);">BOT running function directly</button>

</body>
</html>
```

NB: For the last button, we are simulating a BOT here through a button so we have the luxury of passing the human onclick event to get through, but that won't be the case for a BOT and hence the boolean variable I added.

Comment: Puppeteer / Selenium events will be trusted, I don't know who you expect to stop with that. Maybe chrome extensions?

Comment: @pguardiario yes, chrome extensions would be blocked. As an extension developer, I would hope sites wouldn't implement this feature as it would make it harder to build extensions which, in many cases, add value to the site and enrich user experience.

Comment: bot calling `someFunction({isTrusted: true})` gets around this easily anyway.